# How do I get my area51.stackexchange.com profile deleted?

Tags: support

There is no obviously apparent way to request that sites profile to be removed like on all the other sites.

## How do I get that profile removed?

Comment: This is also explained in the FAQ [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account): as Area 51 runs off an earlier code base from a time when all account deletions had to be processed manually, you must contact SE to request deletion of that account.